# iOS Push notification not showing on LockScreen

Tags: ios, push-notification, apns-php

In my app, I have this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

However, when I send notification from my web server via [ApnsPHP](https://github.com/duccio/ApnsPHP), badge is actualized, but there is no message on lock screen. Message can be found only in notification center.

Do I have to do something more to enable notifications on Lock Screen ?

Comment: Are you sure you have enabled your app in the system preferences app to display its notifications on the lock screen?

Comment: Yes, I have checked that.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that Do Not Disturb is turned off. Go to Settings > Do Not Disturb.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you're json for push notification is not well formatted.Please look at this [article](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

**Small example :**

```
"aps": {
         "badge": 11,
         "alert": "Hello world!"
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn´t that be handled by ApnsPHP library ?

Comment: Debug and see what response you get. From my point of view it seams to me JSON is not well formatted.